# How to use dplyr package to convert the columns to list in a collapsed dataest

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, I want to split the data frame according to the conditions(say the *Species* variable in *iris* dataset) and then for each column I want to convert them to list which allows me to output it into matlab as a structure, I have tried this with the *base* package use `split` command,How can I understand the `interaction` parameter I used within the `split` command to get 12 slices I desired? How can I achieve this with the dplyr package?

```
data <- split(unlist(iris[,c(1:4)]), f=interaction(iris$Species, 
rep(names(iris)[c(1:4)], each=150)))
length(data)
data
names(data)<-gsub("\\.", "_", names(data_list1))
library(rmatio)
write.mat(data, 'demo.mat')
```

Comment: Please clean up your codes. Some inconsistencies include: no information on `data_list1` given, calling for `length(data)` and `data` not relevant to the question, unknown reason why `library(rmatio)` was called.

Comment: `lapply(split(iris[-5], iris$Species), as.list)`? dplyr is for data.frames, not lists. If anything, that would be purrr.

Comment: @alistaire  your answer looks neat.